# How GROUP BY with two inner join in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new in SQL, I have a basic question. I have 3 tables and 2 inner joins. 
This is my SQL code:

```
select   c.name, case when e.time > NOW() then 'Yes' else  'No' end AS "time" 
from table1 as e 
INNER JOIN table2 as a on e.id = a.id  
INNER JOIN table3 as c on a.id = c.id 
where e.conty= 'SAD'  
GROUP BY  c.name;
```

Error: `must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Your `CASE` expression makes no sense here, because it refers to individual records, when your `GROUP BY` means that Postgres must report in terms of _groups_ of records.  Please add sample data.

Comment: Why not remove the `GROUP BY`, I see no use for it? Did you mean to use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: I want to list only one for one name.

Comment: Which one? The one with the minimum or maximum time, or something else?

Comment: Sounds like another [tag:greatest-n-per-group] question

Answer (score 0):

Any field you want to retrieve must be contained in the `GROUP BY` clause of that query. You should include "time" in the `GROUP BY` clause or exclude it from the query.

```
select   c.name, case when e.time > NOW() then 'Yes' else  'No' end AS "time" 
from table1 as e 
INNER JOIN table2 as a on e.id = a.id  
INNER JOIN table3 as c on a.id = c.id 
where e.name = 'JOHN'  
GROUP BY  c.name, time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the e.time attribute in the GROUP BY clause.

```
select c.name, case when e.time > NOW() then 'Yes' else  'No' end AS "time" 
from table1 as e 
INNER JOIN table2 as a on e.id = a.id  
INNER JOIN table3 as c on a.id = c.id 
where e.name = 'JOHN'  
GROUP BY c.name, e.time;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want aggregation -- and the maximum time:

```
select c.name,
       (case when max(e.time) > NOW() then 'Yes' else  'No' end) AS "time" 
from table1 e join
     table2 a
     on e.id = a.id  join
     table3 c
     on a.id = c.id 
where e.name = 'JOHN'  
group by c.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `group by name` since you select only the rows with `name = 'JOHN'`. 
If you want to select the row with the maximum `time`, do this:

```
select   
  'JOHN' name, 
  case when max(e.time) > NOW() then 'Yes' else  'No' end AS "time" 
from table1 as e 
INNER JOIN table2 as a on e.id = a.id  
INNER JOIN table3 as c on a.id = c.id 
where e.name = 'JOHN'
```